# What is the meaning of 'Analytic Isomorphism'?

Tags: definition, modular-forms

I am reading the book "Problems in the Theory of Modular Forms: M. Ram Murty" Chapter-3, Exercise 3.1.4. In this, I need to show that the map $$ z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i} $$
is an analytic isomorphism from the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ to the unit disk $$\mathbb{D}=\{w \in \mathbb{C}: |w|<1\}.$$ Since the map is defined on the upper half-plane which is not a group with respect to addition or multiplication, in what sense, we call the above map to be an 'Isomorphism'? Is it just a set bijection? Any clarification in this regard would be appreciated!

Comment: A bijection that is analytic in both directions ... This is an isomorphims in a suitable category, and not all categories are the category of groups.

Comment: It means an [bi-holomorphic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biholomorphism) : $f(z) : A \to B$ is holomorphic and $f^{-1}(z) : B \to A$ too. The idea is that it is easy to construct a real analytic isomorphic map $A \to B$, but it is much harder to make it complex analytic. Indeed, the only bi-holomorphisms $H \to D$ or $D \to D$ (or $H \to H$ or $D \to H$) are Möbius transformations.

Comment: And something natural (in particular in the context of modular forms) is to consider the ring of analytic (= holomorphic) functions on $A$ and (its field of fraction) the field of meromorphic functions on $A$, and to say that a bi-holomorphic map $A \to B$ induces a field isomorphism with the field of meromorphic functions on $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the map is bi-holomorphic. The map is the well-known ["Cayley-transform"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Conformal_map). There is a generalization $\Phi\colon G\rightarrow {\rm Lie}(G)$ defined on groups, if you want groups, namely on certain algebraic groups and Lie groups. For this see the interesting article by [Kostant and Michor](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kostant.pdf).